# PHP sort a dimension of multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, sorting

there's nothing much to explain, i'll straight get to the sample code:

```
<?php
$array[0]['a'] = 3;
$array[0]['b'] = 2;
$array[0]['c'] = 4;
$array[0]['d'] = 1;

$array[1]['a'] = 4;
$array[1]['b'] = 2;
$array[1]['c'] = 3;
$array[1]['d'] = 1;

$array[2]['a'] = 1;
$array[2]['b'] = 2;
$array[2]['c'] = 4;
$array[2]['d'] = 3;
?>
```

after sorting, it should look like:

```
<?php

$array[0]['d'] = 1;
$array[0]['b'] = 2;
$array[0]['a'] = 3;
$array[0]['c'] = 4;


$array[1]['d'] = 1;
$array[1]['b'] = 2;
$array[1]['c'] = 3;
$array[1]['a'] = 4;

$array[2]['a'] = 1;
$array[2]['b'] = 2;
$array[2]['d'] = 3;
$array[2]['c'] = 4;
?>
```

can't really get my head around it. in a nutshell: i don't wanna sort whole array, but instead i wanna sort specific dimensions of an array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `foreach` to go down a level, and then sort each subarray. There are a few ways you can do this:

```
foreach($arr as &$sub) asort($sub);
// OR
foreach($arr as $k=>$sub) asort($arr[$k]);
// OR
foreach(array_keys($arr) as $k) asort($arr[$k]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to sort directly you index :

`ksort($array[0]);`

To sort all index :

```
foreach($array as $index => $val){ 
    asort($val);
    $array[$index] = $val; 
}
```